# Angular Pwa not refreshing html on installed app

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I've an **Angular PWA** with refreshing problem.
I have a **TAB disabled**.

```
<nz-collapse-panel [nzActive]="false" [nzDisabled]="true">
```

Now on the code i set this tab to **enabled** and build the solution and deployed on the webspace.

```
<nz-collapse-panel [nzActive]="false" [nzDisabled]="false">
```

If a go to the **PWA** and **refresh**, this Collapse **remain disabled**. I must reload the page more and more time and at the end, the Tab is enabled.

I close and reopen the app, the tab is disabled...

The data is correct and refreshed. **It seem's only the HTML is using some cache that is not refreshed**.

The strange thing is that **after reload the page more time, the TAB become enabled** (so i think have update the cache) and **when reopen the app**, the TAB is **disabled again.**

Also the menù doesn't refresh the list. It seems only html element's are not refreshing.

My configuration is with Angular 11 with Ng-Zorro

P.s
Obviously if i go on browser on Developer Tool -> Application -> Delete site data, the cache is cleared and the PWA is Updated but on mobile phone i can't and i don't want to do this

This is my ngsw file:

```
{
"version": 3,
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
"index": "/index.html",
"assetGroups": [
    {
        "name": "app",
        "installMode": "prefetch",
        "resources": {
            "files": ["/favicon.ico", "/index.html", "/manifest.webmanifest", "/*.css", "/*.js"]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "assets",
        "installMode": "lazy",
        "updateMode": "prefetch",
        "resources": {
            "files": ["/assets/**", "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"]
        }
    }
],
"cacheConfig": {
    "strategy": "freshness"
}
```

}

and my appcomponent file

```
constructor(public baseService: BaseService, public webapi: WebapiService, private swUpdate: SwUpdate) {
    this.baseService.initialize();
    this.baseService.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    //#region Check for updates
    if (this.swUpdate.isEnabled) {
        this.swUpdate.activated.subscribe((upd) => {
            window.location.reload();
        });
        this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(
            (upd) => {
                this.swUpdate.activateUpdate();
            },
            (error) => {
                console.error(error);
            }
        );
        this.swUpdate
            .checkForUpdate()
            .then(() => {})
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Could not check for app updates', error);
            });
    }
    //#endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@angular/pwa contains a service worker that caches your entire angular app. To have it updated you must:

1. update your `ngsw-config.json` by adding a `"version": 1,` field at root level. Increment the version on each deploy.
2. Call upon `SwUpdate`:

Code sample:

```
constructor(private swUpdate: SwUpdate) {
  //#region Check for updates
  if (this.swUpdate.isEnabled) {
    this.swUpdate.activated.subscribe((upd) => {
      window.location.reload();
    });
    this.swUpdate.available.subscribe((upd) => {
      this.swUpdate.activateUpdate();
    }, (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
    this.swUpdate.checkForUpdate().then(() => {
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error('Could not check for app updates', error);
    });
  }
  //#endregion
}
```

I've experienced that it's not always necessary to increment the version on each new deploy, but I do it anyway.

[Here's my ngsw-config.json](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MP.Web/ClientApp/ngsw-config.json)

Comment: Thank you i will test it immediately. I have tried this solution without success but i haven't added "version": 1 at root level.

The Code Sample you write here must be placed on constructor ofa App.component.cs , correct?

Comment: Yes, I've put it in the AppComponent

Comment: Thank you , it seem's that work but i have a question. I open the ngsw.json that i load after deploy and in this file ther's no reference to versione. Instead i see ther's configVersion.

Comment: Nothing, i close and then reopen the app and the tab is disabled again...
I fixed the message on the top with my code